# Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome Dock not working

Tags: ubuntu

The Gnome default dock is not working, the entries are the default ones and not the one I had, if I unpin some entry it disappears for some seconds and then it get pinned again, if I pin some program it gets unpinned, also my desktop image is disappeared and now I have the default one.

This problem appeared after a restart of the computer, how can I get it work again?

Comment: By "dock", it sounds like you're referring to one of the desktop UIs like the Cairo dock or a panel?  What desktop environment are you using, and what specific "dock"?  Was this working for awhile and suddenly became problematic, or is this a new installation or newly installed feature that hasn't worked correctly from the start?  With issues of this nature, common problems are corruption or hard drive problems, or updates that create compatibility or dependency issues.  If you just installed the dock as an added feature, it may just not be fully compatible, (cont'd)

Comment: even if it came from the Ubuntu repository.  The symptoms are too generic to be diagnostic without more detail.  You could try running fsck to check for corruption.  If you've been using a program like Timeshift or make regular backups, you could roll back to a point where things were working.  If /home is in a separate partition, it can be pretty straightforward to reinstall Ubuntu without losing your files.  Edit the question to add as much configuration and diagnostic detail as you can so people have more to work with.

Comment: Yes it's the Gnome UI, I'm not sure Dock it's the right name but is the default launch menu on the desktop, it was working and after a restart it stopped. As you @fixer1234 said I suspect it's a hard disk corruption since running `sudo badblocks -v /dev/sdax` gives a bunch of bad blocks.
I will try to reinstall Ubuntu, thank you for your help!